# Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'row' used with directive 'uiGridHeaderCell'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I am trying to use radio button in header cell template in my directive

```
headerCellTemplate: '<label><input ng-model="row.entity.selected" type="radio"  value="true"> Option 1 </label>',
```

My directive

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: linker,
    templateUrl: 'dist/application/a/b/c/test.html',
    scope: {
        data: '=',
        gridTitle:'@',
        gridId:'@'
    }
};
```

The option button shows in header cell but when i click on it i get the following error

> [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'row' used
>   with directive 'uiGridHeaderCell' is non-assignable!

I checked on angular site [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=row&p2=uiGridHeaderCell) but didn't understand how to resolve it.

Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `row` in `headerCellTemplate`. In the `headerCellTemplate` you don't have access to the `row`. Change your `ng-model` to something appropriate and it should work.